# Can I reimplement something like TogglerBox?

Tags: front-end, undocumented

As a purely academic exercise can I make a box structure that'll toggle between two views when clicked and that doesn't ever depend on `Dynamic` or `DynamicBox?`

Answer (score 7):

We'll do this with the `` FEPrivate`* `` functions and a whole bunch of `TemplateBox` tricks. First we start off with a box that'll toggle between two views based on a `test`:

```
FESelectorBox[
   data_List,
   test_,
   expr1_,
   expr2_
   ] :=
  With[{t = test[#3]},
   TemplateBox[
    Join[
     data, 
     {
      RowBox@{"{", data[[1]], ",", data[[2]], ",", ToBoxes@data[[3]], 
        "}"}, 
      ToBoxes@test, ToBoxes@expr1, ToBoxes@expr2}
     ],
    "FESelector",
    DisplayFunction ->
     (
      TemplateBox[
        data,
        "FESelectorInterior",
        DisplayFunction -> (
          FEPrivate`If[
           FEPrivate`SameQ[t, True],
           expr1,
           expr2
           ]
          )
        ] &
      ),
    InterpretationFunction ->
     (
      RowBox@{
         "FESelector", "[",
         #4, ", ", #5, ", ", #6, ", ", #7,
         "]"
         } &
      )
    ]
   ];
```

Next we create a nice wrapper for that box in the normal way:

```
MakeBoxes[
  FESelector[
   data_List,
   test_,
   expr1_,
   expr2_
   ], 
  StandardForm
  ] :=
 FESelectorBox[
  {ToBoxes@data[[1]], ToBoxes@data[[2]], data[[3]]},
  test,
  expr1,
  expr2
  ]
Options[FESelector] = {
   "DisplayFunctions" ->
    {
     True -> (# &),
     False -> (#2 &),
     Indeterminate -> (#2 &)
     },
   "DisplayTest" -> ({##}[[-1]] &)
   };
FESelector[
  data : {true_, false_, testDat_}, 
  ops : OptionsPattern[]
  ] :=
 Module[
  {
   test = OptionValue["DisplayTest"], 
   funcs = OptionValue["DisplayFunctions"]
   },
  If[! OptionQ@funcs,
   funcs = OptionValue[FESelector, {}, "DisplayFunctions"]
   ];
  FESelector[
   data, 
   test,
   Lookup[funcs, True, (# &) ],
   Lookup[funcs, False, (#2 &) ]
   ]
  ]
```

Then we hijack ``EventHandler`to execute switching code of some`CurrentValue`that our`TemplateBox` will depend on but in such a way as to never call into the kernel:

```
FECurrentValueToggle[
  {a_, b_},
  target : Except[_String | _List] : FrontEnd`EvaluationNotebook[],
  key_
  ] :=
 FESelector[
  {a, b, key},
  "DisplayTest" -> (FrontEnd`CurrentValue[target, #] &),
  "DisplayFunctions" -> {
    True -> (
      TagBox[
        #,
        EventHandlerTag[
         {
          "MouseClicked" ->
           FEPrivate`FrontEndExecute@
            FrontEnd`SetValue[
             FEPrivate`Set[
              FrontEnd`CurrentValue[target, #3],
               False
              ]
             ],
          Evaluator -> None,
          PassEventsDown -> False,
          PassEventsUp -> True
          }
         ]
        ] &
      ),
    False -> (
      TagBox[
        #2,
        EventHandlerTag[
         {
          "MouseClicked" ->
           FEPrivate`FrontEndExecute@
            FrontEnd`SetValue[
             FEPrivate`Set[
              FrontEnd`CurrentValue[target, #3],
              True
              ]
             ],
          Evaluator -> None,
          PassEventsDown -> False,
          PassEventsUp -> True
          }
         ]
        ] &
      )
    }
  ]
```

And finally we have what we wanted:

```
toggle =
 FECurrentValueToggle[
  {
   Graphics[Disk[]],
    Graphics3D[Sphere[]]
   }, 
  {TaggingRules, "test"}
  ]
```

[image]

And this retains a reproducible `InputForm`:

```
toggle // InputForm

FESelector[{Graphics[Disk[{0, 0}]], Graphics3D[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}]], 
  {TaggingRules, "test"}}, FrontEnd`CurrentValue[FrontEnd`EvaluationNotebook[], 
   #1] & , 
 TagBox[#1, EventHandlerTag[{"MouseClicked" -> FEPrivate`FrontEndExecute[
       FrontEnd`SetValue[FEPrivate`Set[FrontEnd`CurrentValue[
          FrontEnd`EvaluationNotebook[], #3], False]]], Evaluator -> None, 
     PassEventsDown -> False, PassEventsUp -> True}]] & , 
 TagBox[#2, EventHandlerTag[{"MouseClicked" -> FEPrivate`FrontEndExecute[
       FrontEnd`SetValue[FEPrivate`Set[FrontEnd`CurrentValue[
          FrontEnd`EvaluationNotebook[], #3], True]]], Evaluator -> None, 
     PassEventsDown -> False, PassEventsUp -> True}]] & ]
```

Comment: Interesting.  Is this way of doing it generally faster than Dynamic?